# Blender render in GE?

Tags: rendering, game-engine, logic-bricks

I noticed that when you create a new scene, you have the option to change it from, for example, game engine to render. I also noticed that you can add overlay scenes, which is how I do my menu for example. Would it be possible to have sort of a cut scene in the render engine? As in, you play the game in the game engine, then you reach a certain point and you cannot move as the scene is suspended, and the overlay scene in the render engine is shown. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: No. But it sounds to me like it would be much easier to render the cutscene normally (even from another blendfile), then have the GE play back the resulting video file at the proper time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no that's not possible at all.

The rendering engine selector is more or less just a toggle to change some UI displays. It it not linked to a particular scene in any real way. Besides, Blender Render is hardly capable of rendering a cut scene in realtime. Additionally, Blender Render is not available in blenderplayer.

If you want to display a cutscene in-game, create it in Blender Render or Cycles or whatever first, then render it out to a video file. Finally, in the game engine, play back that video using videotexture.